# ffmpeg node js s3 stream screenshots qestion

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

On my Node js server I need get video from s3, generate thumbnail for it, set thumbnail to s3, without saving video or thumbnail on my server. So I need to use streams for this. For thumbnail generation I use fluent-ffmpeg.

Is it possible to get screenshots from streams using fluent-ffmpeg?

Is the correct way to intercept s3 getObject stream, that there was no need to download full video?

```
var config = require('../config');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: config.AWS_accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: config.AWS_secretAccessKey,
  region: 'eu-west-1'
});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var fs = require('fs');
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

exports.generateVideoThumbnail = function(fileId, url, done) {
  var params = {
    Bucket: config.AWS_bucket,
    Key: url
  };
  var input = s3.getObject(params);
  var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./screenshot.png');
  return ffmpeg(input).screenshots({
    timestamps: ['0.1', '0.2'],
    size: '200x200'
  }).output('./screenshot.png').output(stream).on('error', function(err) {
    return done(err);
  }).on('end', function() {
    input.close();
    var _key = "files/" + fileId + "/thumbnail.png";
    return s3.putObject({
      Bucket: config.AWS_bucket,
      Key: _key,
      Body: stream,
      ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
    }, function(err) {
      return done(err);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: if fluent accepts streams then this could work.  FFmpeg can accept URL's if that helps